# Park transform, why do we use the electric angle and not the mechanical angle?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, brushless-dc-motor

In the control of a motor with a multi pole-pair permanent magnet rotor the Park transform is done (if I am correct) using the electrical angle, and not the mechanical angle.
If we use the motor as a generator, the generated wave will be at the frequency of the electric angle, so it makes sense that the opposite (i.e. using the machine as a motor) should use the electric angle as well
BUT
If I imagine the field created by the stator as a magnet that pulls the stator it would make much more sense to imagine it to rotate at the same speed of the rotor, i.e. to use the mechanical angle. What is the fallacy in the argument in support of the mechanical angle? Do you know any books explaining WHY we should use the electric angle and not the mechanical angle from a physical standpoint?

Answer (score 1):

From a physical standpoint you can use both, it's just easier working with the electrical angle. Because every 360° mechanical degree, you are gonna have a repitition of p times what happens in 360° electrical degree. (p=number of pole pairs)